# Как работают модули и module.exports в node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вопрос по работе модулей и module.exports в node js. В скринкасте по node js Ильи Кантора (http://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/nodejs) в шестом видео "Приемы работы с модулями" натолкнулась на такую запись:

```
module.exports = exports = this
```

Ни в каких других источниках больше не нашла указания, что this ссылается на module.exports, хотя это действительно так. Я никак не могу понять, каким образом происходит эта ссылка. Видно не до конца понимаю, как работают модули и экспорт из них. Буду благодарна за объяснение.

Comment: [в исходнике явно выставляется `exports` как `this`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/19f700859b55b96c7ed9bdeb68482c6a9d84e1b2/lib/module.js#L423) не совсем понятно почему

Comment: Я новичок. Смотрела исходник, но не поняла. Не подскажите в районе каких строк смотреть? Примерные номера? Или копипаст участка кода?

Comment: Увидела, что есть ссылка. Спасибо

Comment: Я докопал до [2009 года](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blame/b6fe4aec5017121fba5baebf50fc76f34d7eb626/src/node.js#L105). Похоже это наследие первых версий, когда модули ещё даже не были CommonJS

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию